# TeamViewer SDK reference page giving error 404

Tags: android, api, sdk, teamviewer

I'm developing a solution for blind users. After doing some research, i decided to use the TeamViewer SDK to create my solution.

When I started investigating the best tools for this, I saw lots of documentation with examples on how to get started with the SDK.

However, the links i followed are all returning a 404 error, and I cannot access the begginers guide anywhere. Does anyone know what's happening?

This was the link that had the information i wanted (it's been almost two weeks since i cannot access that website.

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/screen-sharing-sdk/

I've tried using a VPN to access it though a different country, but it did not help. I'm on Win10, and tried using Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Any help dould be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have a new link: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/for-developers/screen-sharing-sdk/

Your project sounds amazing. Feel free to contact me if you have anything to show and maybe we can support you.

Cheers, Daniel

Comment: How to add teamviewer sdk to android app

Comment: The new link appears to 404 as well.